# Slow static file downloads on virtual server

Tags: apache-2.2

**The problem** is that if I download a file over a domain the download completes in milliseconds but if I download the same file from the other domain the download is starting slow and at the end is returning a **timeout** (if the file is big, like 2MB, but if the file is like 100Kb it's being downloaded properly).

Let me explain a bit more:

I have a local server where I have set up the following structure.

```
www/
    index.html
    2mb.pdf
    blog/
         wp-content/
         2mb.pdf
         wordpress.structure
```

I am using apache2 in Debian with 2 virtual servers with the following domains and configurations (these are not the real names) **freefri.com** and **freefriblog.com**.

**freefri.com**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
```

**freefriblog.com**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName freefriblog.com
    HostnameLookups Off
    EnableSendfile off
    KeepAlive off
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/blog>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/freefriblog-access.log common
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/freefriblog-error.log
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

So, if I open a web brower and type `freefri.com/2mb.pdf`, the file is instantly downloaded. If I type `freefri.com/blog/2mb.pdf`, the file is also instantly downloaded. But If I type`freefriblog.com/2mb.pdf` the request is getting a timeout. The same is happening with all static files like .png or .jpg that are bigger than, let's say, 800KB. Downloading an image from freefriblog.com I am getting the console error "Image corrupt or truncated" but the same image from freefri.com is instantly downloaded.

During the download the apache2 CPU usage is increasing. Maybe apache could be doing some kind of processing over the file like GZIP, but I don't see gzip in the response headers.

I don't see anything strange in the logs

May be that the wordpress is doing something weird? Some rewrite rule?

I could add more details, like the .htaccess, but I don't want to spam the post now, just ask for anything in the comments and I add it. I could also perform any test since it is not a production site.

Comment: `Some rewrite rule?` Well, do you have any? e.g. in `.htaccess` files?

Comment: I have tried to remove the `.htaccess` file and restart the web server and the problem is still there.

Comment: Could you run a packet capture when making a request for freefriblog.com/2mb.pdf and upload it somewhere. I'd like to take a look over it.

Comment: @MarkoPolo good idea a package inspection, unfortunatly I dont have a lot of knowledge about it. I feel pretty bad showing publicly all these IPs and package data, write me an email to adrian@courseticket.com and I will email a wireshark capture you.